# strcpy: detected source and destination buffer overlap

Tags: c, strcpy

This is my implementation of Conway's Game of Life.

I'm currently trying to implement *repetition detection*, which allows the program to detect repetitions with periods up to 4 generations long. For this purpose, I use a list called `statelist` that is intended to store a trail of 4 states behind the current state (the states are represented as a string created by the function `serialize_board()`). To push a new state onto the `statelist`(and possibly discard the last state in the trail), I have implemented the `push_list()` function. But in the `push_list()` function, there is an error:

```
2017-07-18 13:26:32.496180+0100 Assignment 3[38082:4064098] detected source and destination buffer overlap
```

The desired functionality of `push_list` is described in a comment by the function initialization. I don't understand how the strings can overlap. I have allocated enough memory for the `statelist` and `nrows*ncols+1` bytes of memory for each string, which is the size of each state string. Sorry for the lengthy program but it's hard to make it shorter when so many functions depend on each other.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_COORDINATE_SIZE 50
#define MAX_FILENAME_SIZE 20
#define MAX_GENERATIONS 10
#define MAX_REPETITION_PERIOD 4

struct coord{ //Holds coordinates to a cell
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct cell{
    int pop;    //Populated
    //    char pos; //C: corner, T: top, R: right, B: bottom, L: left
    int age;

};

struct coord *read_init(FILE *fp, int *i);

static int read_line(FILE *fp, char *line, int max_length);

struct coord read_coords(char *line);

struct cell **create_board(int x, int y);

void populate_board(struct coord *coords, struct cell ***board, int *n);

struct cell new_cell(int x, int y, int pop, int age);

struct cell **start_game(FILE *fp, int nrows, int ncols);

void print_board(struct cell **board, int nrows, int ncols);

void init_board(int nrows, int ncols, struct cell ***board);

int live(int i, int j, struct cell **board, int nrows, int ncols);

void step(struct cell ***board, int nrows, int ncols);

void push_list(char **list, int len, char *state);

int repetitive(char **list, int len);

char *serialize_board(struct cell **board, int nrows, int ncols);


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int gens;
    char gens_string[MAX_GENERATIONS];
    if(argc != 3){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <seed-file> <generations>\n<seed-file> can me up to %d characters long\n", argv[0], MAX_FILENAME_SIZE);
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    strncat(gens_string, argv[2], MAX_GENERATIONS);
    gens = atoi(gens_string);

    int nrows = 10;
    int ncols = 10;

    int repetitions;

    //allocate memory and set up pointers for statelist
    char **statelist;
    statelist = malloc((MAX_REPETITION_PERIOD+1) * sizeof(char *) + (MAX_REPETITION_PERIOD+1+1) * nrows * ncols); //MAXREP+1 is the number of strings we want to store. The other +1 is to fit in the null temrinator
    char *firstrow = statelist + MAX_REPETITION_PERIOD+1;
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_REPETITION_PERIOD+1; i++){
        statelist[i] = firstrow + i * nrows * ncols;
    }

    struct cell **board= start_game(fp, nrows, ncols);
    print_board(board, nrows, ncols);

    push_list(statelist, MAX_REPETITION_PERIOD+1, serialize_board(board, nrows, ncols));

    struct timespec t;
    t.tv_sec = 0;
    t.tv_nsec = 500000000L;
    for(int i = 0; i < gens; i++){
        step(&board, nrows, ncols);
        nanosleep(&t, NULL);
        print_board(board, nrows, ncols);
        push_list(statelist, MAX_REPETITION_PERIOD+1, serialize_board(board, nrows, ncols));
        if((repetitions = repetitive(statelist, MAX_REPETITION_PERIOD+1))){
            printf("Repetition detected (%d)\n", repetitions);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

struct coord *read_init(FILE *fp, int *n){ //Takes in filename and returns list of coordinates to be populated
    char raw_n[100];
    struct coord *coords;
    char *line;
    line = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_COORDINATE_SIZE);

    read_line(fp, raw_n, 100); // get the first line of the file (number of popuated cells)

    *n = atoi(raw_n);//make an int out of raw_n

    coords = malloc(sizeof(struct coord)*(*n)); //Allocate memory for each coord

    for(int i = 0; i<(*n); i++){ // for each line in the file (each populated cell)
        read_line(fp, line, MAX_COORDINATE_SIZE);
        coords[i] = read_coords(line); //Put coordinates in coords
        line[0] = '\0';
    }

    return coords; // return coordinates
}

static int read_line ( FILE *fp, char *line, int max_length)
{
    int i;
    char ch;
    /* initialize index to string character */
    i = 0;
    /* read to end of line, filling in characters in string up to its
     maximum length, and ignoring the rest, if any */
    for(;;)
    {
        /* read next character */
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        /* check for end of file error */
        if ( ch == EOF )

            return -1;
        /* check for end of line */
        if ( ch == '\n' )
        {
            /* terminate string and return */
            line[i] = '\0';
            return 0;
        }
        /* fill character in string if it is not already full*/
        if ( i < max_length )
            line[i++] = ch;
    }
    /* the program should never reach here */
    return -1;
}

struct coord read_coords(char *line){ // Returns coordinates read from char *line
    struct coord c;
    char *x;
    char *y;
    x = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_COORDINATE_SIZE);
    y = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_COORDINATE_SIZE);

    int i = 0;
    do{
        x[i] = line[i]; //Get the x coordinate
        i++;
    }while(line[i] != ' ');
    i++;
    do{
        y[i-2] = line[i];
        i++;
    }while(line[i] != '\0');

    c.x = atoi(x)-1;
    c.y = atoi(y)-1;

    return c;
}

void init_board(int nrows, int ncols, struct cell ***board){

    *board = malloc(nrows * sizeof(*board) + nrows * ncols * sizeof(**board));

    //Now set the address of each row or whatever stackoverflow says
    struct cell * const firstrow = *board + nrows;
    for(int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    {
        (*board)[i] = firstrow + i * ncols;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < nrows; i++){ //fill the entire board with pieces
        for(int j = 0; j < ncols; j++){
            (*board)[i][j] = new_cell(i, j, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}

struct cell new_cell(int x, int y, int pop, int age){ //Return new populated or non-populated cell with specified coordinates
    struct cell c;
    c.pop = pop;
    c.age = age;
    return c;
}

struct cell **start_game(FILE *fp, int nrows, int ncols){ //x,y are no of rows/columns, fn is filename
    int n; // n is the number of populated cells specified in the seed
    struct coord *coords = read_init(fp, &n); // get the list of coords to populate board with
    struct cell **board;

    init_board(nrows, ncols, &board); // Set up the board

    populate_board(coords, &board, &n); //populate the cells specified in the seed

    return board;
}

void populate_board(struct coord *coords, struct cell ***board, int *n){
    for(int i = 0; i < *n; i++){
        (*board)[coords[i].x][coords[i].y].pop = 1; //populate the cell
    }
}

void print_board(struct cell **board, int nrows, int ncols){
    printf("--------------------\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<nrows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<ncols; j++){
            if(board[i][j].pop == 1){
                printf("%d ", board[i][j].age);
            }else if(board[i][j].pop == 0){
                printf("  ");
            }else{
                printf("\n\nERROR!");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("--------------------");
    printf("\n");
}

int live(int i, int j, struct cell **board, int nrows, int ncols){ //returns 1 if cell will live, 0 if cell will die,

    int status = board[i][j].pop; // status = 1 if alive, 0 if dead
    int n=0; //neighbours

    //Counting all the neighbours

    if(i == 0 && j == 0){    //if top left cornerpiece
        if(board[i][j+1].pop)  { n++; } // east
        if(board[i+1][j+1].pop){ n++; } // southeast
        if(board[i+1][j].pop)  { n++; } // south
    }
    else if(i == 0 && j==ncols-1){ //if top right cornerpiece
        if(board[i+1][j].pop)  { n++; } // south
        if(board[i+1][j-1].pop){ n++; } // southwest
        if(board[i][j-1].pop)  { n++; } // west
    }
    else if(i == nrows-1 && j == ncols-1){ //if bottom right cornerpiece
        if(board[i][j-1].pop)  { n++; } // west
        if(board[i-1][j-1].pop){ n++; } // northwest
        if(board[i-1][j].pop)  { n++; } // north
    }
    else if(i == nrows-1 && j == 0){ //if bottom left cornerpiece
        if(board[i-1][j].pop)  { n++; } // north
        if(board[i-1][j+1].pop){ n++; } // northeast
        if(board[i][j+1].pop)  { n++; } // east
    }
    else if(i == 0){ // middle top piece (not in a corner)
        if(board[i][j+1].pop)  { n++; } // east
        if(board[i+1][j+1].pop){ n++; } // southeast
        if(board[i+1][j].pop)  { n++; } // south
        if(board[i+1][j-1].pop){ n++; } // southwest
        if(board[i][j-1].pop)  { n++; } // west
    }
    else if(j == ncols-1){ // middle right side piece
        if(board[i+1][j].pop)  { n++; } // south
        if(board[i+1][j-1].pop){ n++; } // southwest
        if(board[i][j-1].pop)  { n++; } // west
        if(board[i-1][j-1].pop){ n++; } // northwest
        if(board[i-1][j].pop)  { n++; } // north
    }
    else if(i == nrows-1){ // middle bottom piece
        if(board[i][j-1].pop)  { n++; } // west
        if(board[i-1][j-1].pop){ n++; } // northwest
        if(board[i-1][j].pop)  { n++; } // north
        if(board[i-1][j+1].pop){ n++; } // northeast
        if(board[i][j+1].pop)  { n++; } // east
    }
    else{
        if(board[i-1][j].pop)  { n++; } // north
        if(board[i-1][j+1].pop){ n++; } // northeast
        if(board[i][j+1].pop)  { n++; } // east
        if(board[i+1][j+1].pop){ n++; } // southeast
        if(board[i+1][j].pop)  { n++; } // south
        if(board[i+1][j-1].pop){ n++; } // southwest
        if(board[i][j-1].pop)  { n++; } // west
        if(board[i-1][j-1].pop){ n++; } // northwest
    }

    if(status){
        if(n < 2)           { return 0; }
        if(n >= 2 && n <= 3){ return 1; }
        if(n > 3)           { return 0; }
    }
    if(!status){
        if(n == 3)          { return 1; }
        return 0;
    }
    //We should never reach here
    return -1;
}

void step(struct cell ***board, int nrows, int ncols){ // returns array of strings that contain all of the 5 latest states
    struct cell **nextgenboard;
    nextgenboard = malloc(nrows*(sizeof(nextgenboard)) + nrows * ncols * sizeof(**nextgenboard));
    struct cell * const firstrow = nextgenboard + nrows;
    for(int i = 0; i < nrows; i++){
        nextgenboard[i] = firstrow + i*ncols;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < nrows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < ncols; j++){

        }
    }
    for(int r = 0; r < nrows; r++){

        for(int c = 0; c < ncols; c++){

            nextgenboard[r][c].pop = live(r, c, *board, nrows, ncols);
            if((*board)[r][c].pop == 0){
                nextgenboard[r][c].age = 0;
            }else if((*board)[r][c].pop == 1){
                nextgenboard[r][c].age = (*board)[r][c].age + 1;
            }

            //nextgenboard[r][c].age = 0;

        }

    }

    free(*board);

    *board = nextgenboard;

}

void push_list(char **list, int len, char *state){ //takes an array of strings, the length of it and a new string. Pushes the other strings down and puts the new string in the first place. The last one gets destroyed.

    //move all the other elements down.
    for(int i = len-1; i > 0; i--){
        strcpy(list[i], list[i-1]); <---- HERE IS THE ERROR
    }
    //put the new element first
    strcpy(list[0], state);
}

int repetitive(char **statelist, int len){ // takes the statelist and checks if the first element reoccurs. Returns 0 for no repetition, and the period otherwise.
    for(int i = 1; i < len; i++){
        if(strcmp(statelist[0], statelist[i]) == 0){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

char *serialize_board(struct cell **board, int nrows, int ncols){
    char *str;
    str = malloc(sizeof(char)*nrows*ncols);

    int z = 0;
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < nrows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < ncols; j++){
            str[z] = board[i][j].pop+48;
            z++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return str;
}
```

EDIT1: Added a comment where the error is generated. My question is: Why does this happen and what can I do about it?

EDIT2:

In his answer, @Neil says my code is effectively doing this:

```
char str[10];
strcpy(&str[1], &str[0]);
```

In an effort to create an example that better models my program (such as str being a char ** rather than a char *), I wrote this:

```
int main(){
    char **str;
    str = malloc(sizeof(char *)*3 + sizeof(char)*3*10);
    char * firststring = str+3;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        str[i] = firststring + i*10;
    }

    strcpy(str[0], "123456789");
    strcpy(str[1], "000000000");

    printf("%s\n", str[0]);
    printf("%s\n", str[1]);

    strcpy(str[1], str[0]);

    printf("%s\n", str[0]);
    printf("%s\n", str[1]);
}
```

Here, I'm using `strcpy` to copy one array element (containing a pointer to a char) to another. This works fine. So why doesn't my code work? I want it to do the same thing in principle as this mini example.

EDIT3:

So a few changes made my program finally do what I want it to.

1. Fix faulty allocation of memory in `main()`.
2. Terminate each string in `statelist` with `'\0'`.
3. Initialize statelist to `\0` (although the program did execute properly with just the two above)

1.:

```
char **statelist;
statelist = malloc((MAX_REPETITION_PERIOD+1) * sizeof(char *) + (MAX_REPETITION_PERIOD+1) * (nrows * ncols + 1) * sizeof(char));
char *firstrow = statelist + MAX_REPETITION_PERIOD+1;
for(int i = 0; i < (MAX_REPETITION_PERIOD+1); i++){
    statelist[i] = firstrow + i * (nrows * ncols + 1);
    *statelist[i] = '\0';
}
```

2.:

```
char *serialize_board(struct cell **board, int nrows, int ncols){
    char *str;
    str = malloc(sizeof(char)*nrows*ncols);

    int z = 0;
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < nrows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < ncols; j++){
            str[z] = board[i][j].pop+48;
            z++;
        }
    }
    str[z] = '\0'; <---- HERE
    return str;
}
```

3.:

See 1.

Comment: Get rid of the warnings first.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: We are not a debugging service. This is far from being **minimal**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `statelist` contains a bunch of pointers into uninitialized memory. When you try to `strcpy` from one of these pointers, this causes undefined behavior.

But even if you initialize the memory to zeroes, what you are doing is fundamentally incorrect. You use the `strcpy` function and other `str*` functions, but those functions are only intended for zero-terminated strings. The memory returned by `serialize_board` which you are attempting to `strcpy` is just a a bunch of `char`s that is not zero-terminated. So again you have undefined behavior.

You can use the `memcpy` function instead to copy these chunks of memory since you know the size of memory to copy. You will also need to use `memcpy` instead of `strcmp`.

You also have some serious memory leaks here (e.g. the memory allocated by `serialize_board` is not freed).

Comment: 1. Statelist is initialized in `main()` through the `malloc()`-call and then the for loop after it, just like in my edit2 example.
2. You're right, I didn't terminate the strings with a '\0'-terminator. I will do so and continue to try to get it working.

Comment: @Sandi The memory returned by `malloc` is uninitialized, and you have pointers pointing to it.

Comment: Got it. Fixed the problems you pointed out, except the memory leak which I'm still working on. Specified in Edit3

Answer (score -1):

Here:

```
void push_list(char **list, int len, char *state){ //takes an array of strings, the length of it and a new string. Pushes the other strings down and puts the new string in the first place. The last one gets destroyed.

//move all the other elements down.
for(int i = len-1; i > 0; i--){
    strcpy(list[i], list[i-1]); // <-- HERE
}
//put the new element first
strcpy(list[0], state);
```

}

list is a pointer to pointer to char.  it has no intrinsic length (apart from char*).  The compiler doesn't *know* that a `list[i]` is anything more than 1 byte long.

Effectively, the code you have does:

```
char str[10];
strcpy(&str[1], &str[0]);
```

See how the overlap occurs?

OK, lets try this.

```
1. char str[10] = "ABCDEFGHI";
2. strcpy(&str[1], &str[0]);
```

Imagine you have a 'string' of 9 chars (+1 nul terminator) - line 1.
Line 2 will try and move "BCDEFGHI" into the space occupied by "ABCDEFGHI":

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Perhaps I wasn't being clear. I know that that is the line that causes the problem. But how does your answer explain why the compiler detects overlapping buffers? And what is the solution?

Comment: Imagine you have a string that is 10 characters long.  You are asking strcpy to copy from position 0 for 10 characters to position 1 (in the same string)

Comment: Am I not passing push_list an array of arrays of chars? And if so, why can't I simply copy one array of chars to another place in the array?

Comment: And I don't see the overlap in your example, no. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Remember, chars are not 'strings'.  C doesn't have 'strings'.  The C library has a concept of an array of chars with a nul terminator is a 'string', but that's not what you have here.  You are 1 large chunk of memory and you reference the start of the block as a char *

Comment: So what happens is `list[i]` returns everything after that element in the whole big chunk of memory? and `list[i-1]` returns everything after that element?

Comment: I understand your point Neil, but I have a feeling my problem is different. See my second edit to see why.

Comment: The `push_list` function itself is not wrong, it is the input to it which is incorrect. Your examples are nothing like what `push_list` does, because they don't have the extra level of pointers.